# Endomorphism ring of module quotient radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $R$ be a ring of arbitrary characteristic and let $A$ be an $R$-module. Denote  $\mathrm{Rad}(A)$ as the radical of $A$ (i.e. the the intersection of maximal submodules). Then do we have
$$
 \mathrm{End}(A/\mathrm{Rad}(A)) \cong \mathrm{End}(A) / 
 \mathrm{Rad}\big(\mathrm{End}(A)\big),
$$
when $A$ is not necessarily semisimple but $A/\mathrm{Rad}(A)$ is semisimple?

If this is not generally true, then in what generality does this hold?

Comment: @rschwieb: Sorry about that, typos fixed!

Answer (score 3):

The result is not true in general. My thinking would be to find a module $M$ of Loewy length two having simple socle $S$ but such that $M/S\cong S^2$.

So, take a field $k$, the four dimensional algebra $R:=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$, and the three dimensional module $M:=\mathrm{rad}(R)$. Then
$$ \mathrm{End}_R(M)\cong R/\mathrm{soc}(R)=k[x,y]/(x,y)^2,$$
so that $\mathrm{End}(M)/\mathrm{rad}\,\mathrm{End}(M)\cong k$, but $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)\cong k^2$, which has endomorphism ring $\mathbb M_2(k)$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but shouldn't $M/\mathrm{Rad}(M) = 0$ since $\mathrm{Rad}(M) = \mathrm{Rad}\big(\mathrm{Rad}(R)\big) = M$?

Nevertheless, what would be sufficient conditions on $A$ for the isomorphism to hold? For instance, why is it the case in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334815/gelfands-trick-gelfands-lemma-in-positive-characteristic)?

Comment: $M$ is finite dimensional, so by Nakayama’s Lemma, $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)=0$ implies $M=0$. Explicitly, $M$ has basis $a,b,c$ and $R$-action $xa=c$, $yb=c$, all other multiplications zero. So $\mathrm{soc}(M)=\langle c\rangle$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! The radical of the radical might not equal just the radical, such as when $M$ is finitely generated. In what generality might the isomorphism hold? Alternatively, what is the precise obstruction?

Comment: I don’t see any condition under which every endomorphism of $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$ can be lifted to an endomorphism of $M$. It is even possible to have a uniserial module where this doesn’t happen. For example take the subring of $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb C)$ having zero in top right position and real entries in bottom right. Then there is a non-simple injective left module having socle $\mathbb R$ and top $\mathbb C$, whose endomorphism ring is $\mathbb R$, but whose top has endomorphism ring $\mathbb C$. This can’t happen if we’re over an algebraically closed field, though.